# Why won't this v-data-table render?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, inertiajs

I'm new to vue.

I'm trying to render a Vuetify v-data-table. The table doesn't render.

**The component**

```
<template>

    <v-data-table
        :items-per-page="5"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        item-value="name"
        class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>

</template>
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            headers: [
                { title: 'Dessert (100g serving)', align: 'start', sortable: false, key: 'name' },
                { title: 'Calories', align: 'end', key: 'calories' },
                { title: 'Fat (g)', align: 'end', key: 'fat' },
                { title: 'Carbs (g)', align: 'end', key: 'carbs' },
                { title: 'Protein (g)', align: 'end', key: 'protein' },
                { title: 'Iron (%)', align: 'end', key: 'iron' },
            ],
            desserts: [
                { name: 'Frozen Yogurt', calories: 159, fat: 6.0, carbs: 24, protein: 4.0, iron: '1',},
            ],
        }
    },
}

</script>
```

**App.js**

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';

// Vuetify
//import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
import * as labsComponents from 'vuetify/labs/components'
const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    labsComponents
})

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .use(vuetify)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

**What I expect to happen**

A simple table to render with one row of data and six columns.

**What happens**

Nothing. The table doesn't render. I can see the component in the DOM. The headers and dessert are passed as objects.

```
<v-data-table items-per-page="5" headers="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" items="[object Object]" item-value="name" class="elevation-1"></v-data-table>
```

I've been struggling with this and could really use some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the spread operator (`...`) with the imported `labsComponents` in App.js. This matches the "usage" instructions in the [Labs documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/#usage).

```js
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components: {
      components,
      ...labsComponents,
  },
  directives
})
```

From my own local testing, the spread operator is optional for `components` and `directives`, but **required** for `labsComponents`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did add the spread operator but it didn't change the result.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't `labsComponents` be merged with components, i.e. createVuetify({`components: {...components, ...labsComponents}, directives})`?

Comment: Indeed, that's the other missing piece.  Answer updated.

Comment: I think "directives" has to be outside of components, doesn't it? Might not make a difference though, depending on setup, Vuetify imports used directives and components anyway. Sorry for being annoying...

Comment: Man. I got so excited. I made the change suggested but i'm still seeing the same result. My createVuetify looks like this now 

`const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components:{
        ...components,
        ...labsComponents
    },
    directives,

})`

I don't get any errors. I'm still not seeing the rendered DataTable.

Comment: Okay. I think i've got it. I made the suggested changes and changed v-data-table to VDataTable and the table now renders. I appreciate the help.